# how to upgrade the version HDF NiFi to the latest?

Tags: apache-nifi

I wanted to upgrade HDF-3.1.2 to 3.5.2 and NiFi 1.5 to 1.11.
I was referring the website docs.cloudera.com but could not clearly understood from where to start with.
my current clusters are:

1. NiFi and Zookeeper - 3 nodes (x.1, x.2, x.3)
2. Kafka - 3 nodes (x.4, x.5, x.6)
3. Ambari/kerberos/Ranger/Grafana - 1 node (x.7)

someone can guide me the procedure that i can follow to complete the upgrade process and the precautionary backup process?

Answer (score 0):

The docs on how to upgrade an HDF cluster are here: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.5.2/index.html

A summary of the process for HDF-3.5.2 upgrade involving NiFi and Kafka is to get your credentials for the Cloudera site, download the new packages, then upgrade Ambari, then upgrade the child NiFi and Kafka services.
If you want to get into more detail on best practice for your particular Deployment you probably want to talk to Cloudera directly.